# docx4j reports differences on unchanged table data

Tags: jaxb, docx4j

I have created a *.docx file with a 2x2 table, each cell containing the text `Cell x-y` where `x`=row number and `y`=column number.

When I pass this document through a simple transformation process, docx4j's `Differencer.diff()` method reports no differences (i.e. no `w:ins` or `w:del` tags).

This is expected  and handled cleanly, inspite of the fact that the .docx has the text of the original document broken up like this inside the `<w:tc> -> <w:p>` tags:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>Cell</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve"> 1-1</w:t>
</w:r>
```

and this in the transformed document:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">Cell 1-1</w:t>
</w:r>
```

However, if I add the text "Table Title" above the table in the document, the contents of the original document (Word's handling, nothing I can do about it) cells merges into one `<w:r>`:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>Cell 1-1</w:t>
</w:r>
```

And the only difference in the transformed document is that `xml:space="preserve"` is inserted:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">Cell 1-1</w:t>
</w:r>
```

*However*, docx4j's `Differencer.diff()` method now reports that the content of each cell is inserted, and shows the following as the content of each `w:tc`'s `w:p` in the generated diff document:

```
<w:ins xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" w:date="2009-03-11T17:57:00Z" w:author="someone" w:id="1">
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Cell 1-1</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:ins>
```

and shows the content of each cell as deleted, immediately following the closing `<w:tbl>` tag:

```
    <!--Handling simple deleted w:p-->
    <w:p xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
        <w:del w:date="2009-03-11T17:57:00Z" w:author="someone" w:id="5">
            <w:r>
                <w:delText>Cell 1-1
            </w:r>
        </w:del>
    </w:p>
```

I know that the Differencer is capable of ignoring the `xml:space="preserve"` attributes because it does so with the inserted text before the table, so I doubt that's the cause.

Are these table scenarios outside the intended use case for the `Differencer`?  Is it an error in usage / invocation?  Bug?

Any guidance is appreciated.